# Как удалить значение из input?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть такая задача: 
Есть модальное окно, которое открывается при клике на Input.В этом модальном юзер выбирает определенные категории. И выбранные категории должны записаться в Input, на который нажали и откуда появилось модальное окно.
Если мы второй раз нажали на выбранную категорию, то она удаляется из Input'a.

1. По логике надо проверить строку через replace, но в Javascript не могу реализовать. Подскажите без использования jQuery
2. А также как удалить последнюю запятую? Если выбрано 1но значение, то запятой не должно быть. Если 2 и более, то надо и у последнего удалить

   jsfiddle.net/m0hsyx9L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно можно и проще, но вот вариант:

```js
const target = document.getElementById('target');
const checkboxs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxs.length; i++) {
  checkboxs[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    send()
  }, false);
}

function send() {
  let value = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxs.length; i++) {
    let el = checkboxs[i];
    if (el.checked) value += ', ' + el.value;
  }
  target.value = value.replace(/^\, +/g, '');
}

send();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0
}

input#target {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<input id="target" disabled></input>

<input type="checkbox" name="email" value="email" checked="true">
<label for="type1">Email</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="phone" value="phone">
<label for="type2">Phone</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="mail" value="mail">
<label for="type3">Mail</label>
```